# Format a bash command in a script

Tags: linux, bash

in the shell i type:

```
bc -l <<< '90.8/(179*179)*10000'
```

and i get the correct output:

```
28.33869105208951030000
```

however i am not able to format this correct in a bash script:

```
calculate_bmi () {
    BMI="$(bc -l <<< '${1}/(${2}*${2})*10000)'"
    echo "${BMI}"
}
```

I get all kind of strange errors when i tried different experiments. Latest error is:

```
./wts.sh: command substitution: line 25: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./wts.sh: command substitution: line 25: `bc -l <<< ${1}/(${2}*${2})*10000)"'
```

Please help me.

Comment: You don't need the variable; just let the output of `bc` go to standard output instead of capturing it. `calculate_bmi () { bc -l <<< "$1/($2*$2)*10000"; }`.

Comment: The echo statement was only for debugging purposes, i think i need a variable since i am writing the value to a csv file together with other data. Anyway, it works as it should at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your function as below:

```
calculate_bmi () {
    BMI=$(bc -l <<< "${1}/(${2}*${2})*10000")
    echo "${BMI}"
}
```

You must use double quotes (rather than single) in order to interpolate the variables.